# What is my neo4j config?

Tags: neo4j

I am testing [Cypher for apache Spark](https://github.com/opencypher/cypher-for-apache-spark) and i need to store a graph created with the help of a dataframe in Neo4j.

to do that , a contributer, answered me that i need to add this two line :

```
val neo4jDS = GraphSources.cypher.neo4j(yourNeo4jConfig)
    neo4jDS.store(Neo4jPropertyGraphDataSource.defaultGraphName, yourGraph)
```

however, since i 'm new to neo4j , i don't understand what he means with **Neo4j Config** ? is it the password?

***how can i know my Neo4j Config ?***

**Note**: I am using Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

Neo4j installation has the config location depending on your platform. If your installation is under /app/neo4j, which is also called as NEO4J_HOME, the configuration will be under /app/neo4j/conf in the file neo4j.conf.